# Picam is 5 frames behind, using OpenCV (C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to take 3 images, separated by a 1s delay. When taking images of a running stopwatch, it shows that the images are just ~30ms apart. The application is running on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+, with a picam v2.1 (set to 30 FPS, and otherwise default settings).  My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat img;
    VideoCapture vcap;

    cout << "Opening camera..." << endl;
    vcap.open(0);
    vcap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0);

    usleep(1000*2000);

    if(vcap.isOpened())
    {
        vcap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920);
        vcap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080);

        cout << "Taking image...(1)" << endl;
        vcap >> img;
        imwrite("img1.jpg", img);

        usleep(1000*1000);

        cout << "Taking image...(2)" << endl;
        vcap >> img;
        imwrite("img2.jpg", img);

        usleep(1000*1000);

        cout << "Taking image...(3)" << endl;
        vcap >> img;
        imwrite("img3.jpg", img);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Could not open camera!" << endl;
    }

    vcap.release();

    return 0;
}
```

I have also tried a infinite loop, where I take an image and display it. This reveals that it takes 5 frames for the camera to be up to date with reality (e.g. if i take an image of my hand, then remove my hand, it takes 5 images before I can see my hand removed).

I have search far and wide, but I can't seem to find others with the same problem.

Please let me know if I need to add further details.

Comment: Why not get the time of day (as hh:mm:ss and possibly fractions of a second) and put it in the `cout ...` statements? You could also put the time into the filenames as they are saved. The `vcap >> img;` might take significant time so it would be worth getting the current time in each statement that uses it. This is a basic debugging technique when handling times, i.e. let the program tell you what it is doing and when.

Comment: many cameras and/or opencv use internal buffers. Those cameras might not be made to capture single/still images. Maybe just capture continuously in a 2nd thread and once you want to trigger your single shot capturing, choose the last or the next image.

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply.. Thank you for your suggestions. They make good sense, and I will try to implement them, as soon as I have the time.